# Cache-Control: before public or max-age?

Tags: http, header

I believe they are both equivalent but to be sure I would like to know others.

Which version is correct?

1. `Cache-Control: public, max-age=60`
2. `Cache-Control: max-age=60, public`

?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's the grammar for the [Cache-Control directive](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2) from RFC 7234:

```
Cache-Control   = 1#cache-directive
cache-directive = token [ "=" ( token / quoted-string ) ]
```

`1#cache-directive` means that you need [at least one](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-7) `cache-directive`. Since `public` and `max-age` are both Cache-Control directives, the **order doesn't matter**.

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent. Order doesn't even make a different in that scenario anyway.